# extract digit numbers to Long number from string in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to extract numbers from string
how can i do that in Kotlin ?

```
81aabf9d-844e-4086-9621-f3afed02e163
```

to

```
81984440869621302163
```

Comment: Result type `String` or any numerical one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this extension function

```
fun String?.extractDigit(): Long {
    if (this == null) {
        return 0
    }
    var nums = this.replace("\\D+".toRegex(), "")
    Log.i("extractDigit", nums)

    if (nums.isEmpty())
        return 0

    return nums.toLong()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [String filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/filter.html):

```
val text= "81aabf9d-844e-4086-9621-f3afed02e163"
val result = text.filter{it.isDigit()}
```